# Double Array Print Out in C is giving me weird output

Tags: c

```
     a = (float**)malloc(num * sizeof(float*));
     if( !a)  {
     printf("Cannot allocate a!\n");
     exit(1);
     }

     for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
     a[i] = (float *)malloc(num * sizeof(float));
     if( !a[i]) {
            printf("Cannot allocate a[%d]!\n",i);
            exit(1);
     }}

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < num; j++)
            fscanf(fp,"%f ",&a[i][j]);
    }


    // in a method called after a is initialized and elements are recorded. 
    int s, t;
    printf("This is num: %d\n", num);
    for (s = 0; s < num; s++) {

            for (t = 0; t < num; t++) {
                    printf("This is a[s][t]:%d for s:%d and t:%d\n", a[s][t], s, t);
            }
    }
```

> This is num: 3
>   This is a[s][t]:0 for s:0 and t:4198765
>   This is a[s][t]:0 for s:1 and t:4199061
>   This is a[s][t]:0 for s:2 and t:4199061
>   This is a[s][t]:1 for s:0 and t:4199061
>   This is a[s][t]:1 for s:1 and t:4199061
>   This is a[s][t]:1 for s:2 and t:4199061
>   This is a[s][t]:2 for s:0 and t:4199061
>   This is a[s][t]:2 for s:1 and t:4199061
>   This is a[s][t]:2 for s:2 and t:4199061

// This is the matrix input
5 1 3 6
3 7 2 8
3 6 9 6

// The ordering is not even right!

Comment: Sorry for the poor format of this question.  First question I made here.  Thanks

Comment: printf's parameter `%f` instead of `%d` for `a[s][t]` (double , float)

Comment: The content of question is completely unclear. Whether it is your first question or thousands you should post the actual question in the post body!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `%f` for printing a float, and also check that each `fscanf` suceeded or failed.